# XML validation in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am building an eclipse plugin in which I need to validate XML files "on the fly".

I created a new content type with **org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml** as base type and a new editor extending **org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor** for this content type. 
I also contributed to the **org.eclipse.wst.validation.validatorV2** to create a validator using the **org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.eclipse.Validator** to validate my XML files.

Here is my plugin.xml

```
<plugin>  
   <extension  
         point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">  
      <content-type  
            base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"  
            file-extensions="example"  
            id="com.example.editor.content.example"  
            name="Example Files"  
            priority="normal">  
      </content-type>  
   </extension>  
   <extension  
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">  
      <editor  
            class="com.example.editor.ExampleEditor"  
            id="com.example.editor.example"  
            name="Example editor">  
         <contentTypeBinding  
               contentTypeId="com.example.editor.content.example">  
         </contentTypeBinding>  
      </editor>  
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="com.example.validator.ExampleValidator"
         name="Example validator"
         point="org.eclipse.wst.validation.validatorV2">
      <validator
            build="true"
            class="org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.eclipse.Validator"
            manual="true">
         <include>
            <rules>
               <contentType
                     id="com.example.editor.content.example">
               </contentType>
            </rules>
         </include>
      </validator>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

The manual validation (Right click -> Validate) works but the file is not validated "on the fly" (i.e while the user types or when the file is saved).

Is there a way to validate the file every time it is saved to show possible errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did notice this error a while ago. This org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor editor fails to include validation to the editor.
Have you tried extending inbuilt XML editor?I guess it is possible coz after extending the content type of XML editor I didn't hat to extend the editor for my extension.
It automatically validated the editor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to try to extend a new XML Editor. I chose to extend the Rinzo XML Editor (http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/) and it does the job.